# How to compile CSS on Visual Studio 2017 Angular template using webpack?

Tags: angular, webpack, visual-studio-2017

Please ignore my ignorance, but I am somewhat new to programming and very new to webpack and Angular.

I have VS 2017 and I created a new project via New Project > ASP.NET Core Web App > and then selected the Angular template under .NET Core/ASP.NET Core 2.0. Webpack is already built into the project. I need to add CSS to the components that I have built, and I need webpack to bundle the CSS for me. Within the project, where do I put my CSS files and how do I run webpack correctly so that it will bundle them?